# How do I use the auto layout to resize image buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I uses the auto layout. It is really cool. But I had a problem to resize image buttons.

I have one image buttons.. it is designed for iPhone 6.

image button size is 46px X 46px.

I want resize this button via the auto layout.

I think... image button's width = 46 x (screen width / 375) <-- 375 means iPhone 6's width...because this button is designed for iPhone6.

for example

in iPhone6

image button's width = 46 x (375/375) = 46.

in iPhone5

image button's width = 46 x (320/375) = 39.2

in iPhone6 plus

image button's width = 46 x (414/375) = 50.78...

But in Xcode.. I can't find how do I set this methods by using the auto layout.

There are only have multiply options..

e.g. select button and super view... and add constrain + multiplies...

but I don't like it...Could you helping me?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you like it? what does it do wrong?

Comment: My wrong is.... how do I set image's width using the auto layout. I've look around the auto layout...and I'm trying to set image button's width by using the equal width function...with button and super view...but I don't know how do I set like this..muliflier as "screen width / 375"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the button to a percentage of the screen width (or the view superview width) using the multiplier, you just need to choose the value.

For a button that you want to be 46 on a superview of 375 that is a percentage of 46/375 = 0.12

You can also check that 0.12*320 = 38.4 and 0.12*414 = 49.68

Add as many decimal places to 0.12 as you want to get the sizes you want. Ideally you'd choose something which resulted in the image being a whole number of pixels wide at each device size...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You means... "add 3 equal width to image's width"? Or just set to multiplier as 0.12?

Comment: i don't know what `add 3 equal to width to image's width` means. yes, to start with just set the multiplier to `0.12` and try it

Comment: I got it. Thanks you so much... Can I have a one more question to you? Um...0.12 is very cool. But in iPhone 6... my Image's width = 45 px..not 46 px right? I'm really appreciate for you :)

Comment: Yes, you'd need something like `0.122666666666` to get closer to 46

Comment: You can set the multiplier to a ratio, and Xcode will do the math for you.  Set the multiplier to `46:375`.

Comment: @vacawama If I use the ratio..then Can I set 3 options? e.g 46:375 for iPhone6 , 39:320 for iPhone5, 50:414 for iPhone6 plus? Is it right?

Comment: If you set the ratio of `46:375`, then Xcode will do the math for you.  On iPhone 5 the width will be `320*46/375`, on iPhone 6Plus, the width will be `414*46/375` and of course on iPhone 6 `375*46/375`.

Comment: @vacawama Wow It's really cool. Thank you for your helping me :)

Comment: nice @vacawama completely forgot about doing that for normal (not aspect) constraints